# Problem loading R packages in Jupyter-lab

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I am using jupyter-lab on Anaconda3. Jupyter-lab is not able to find some R packages.

I installed r-essentials package and shiny is included in it. I already tried updating r-essentials and anaconda.

here is some information:

```
>.libPaths()
'C:/Users/XXX/anaconda3/Lib/R/library'
```

when checking  through `system.file(package='shiny')` it appears as not installed.

If I try to install shiny through  `install.packages("shiny")` I get the following warning message:

```
> install.packages("shiny")

also installing the dependencies 'Rcpp', 'cli', 'httpuv', 'htmltools', 'promises', 'rlang', 'fastmap', 'glue', 'bslib', 'lifecycle'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
Rcpp        1.0.6 1.0.11              TRUE
cli         2.5.0  3.6.1              TRUE
httpuv      1.6.1 1.6.11              TRUE
htmltools 0.5.1.1  0.5.6              TRUE
promises  1.2.0.1  1.2.1              TRUE
rlang      0.4.11  1.1.1              TRUE
fastmap     1.1.0  1.1.1              TRUE
glue        1.4.2  1.6.2              TRUE
bslib       0.2.4  0.5.1             FALSE
lifecycle   1.0.0  1.0.3             FALSE
shiny       1.6.0  1.7.5             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
package 'Rcpp' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'httpuv' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'htmltools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning message:
"cannot remove prior installation of package 'htmltools'"Warning message in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE):
"problema al copiar C:\Users\XXXX\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\00LOCK\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll  a C:\Users\XXXX\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\htmltools\libs\x64\htmltools.dll: Permission denied"Warning message:
"restored 'htmltools'"

package 'promises' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning message:
"cannot remove prior installation of package 'rlang'"Warning message in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE):
"problema al copiar C:\Users\XXXXX\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll  a C:\Users\XXXX\anaconda3\Lib\R\library\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied"Warning message:
"restored 'rlang'"

package 'fastmap' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'glue' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk3IrRV\downloaded_packages

installing the source packages 'bslib', 'lifecycle', 'shiny'

Warning message in install.packages("shiny"):
"installation of package 'bslib' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("shiny"):
"installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("shiny"):
"installation of package 'shiny' had non-zero exit status"
```

If I try to install shiny manually through anaconda prompt I would get a message that is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem creating a new environment in Anaconda3.